# Is The Third Time Derivative of Position Relative, and if it is, Can it be represented in 6 Dimensions?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, jerk

Einstein’s Theory of Special Relativity only applied to objects at constant velocities. This could be represented in a four dimensional Minkowski Space. From what I understand, Einstein compared gravity to acceleration in General Relativity, and this could be represented as gravity warping Minkowski Space, hence, the addition of another dimension. Using this reasoning, is Jerk - the third 
derivative of position - relative, and hence, be represented in six dimensions?

Comment: *"and this could be represented as gravity warping Minkowski Space, hence, the addition of another dimension"* You should not think that warped space necessarily implies embedding in a higher dimensional space. That's the easy way to visualize some geometries but the math does not require it.

Comment: Note that, while it's *possible* to represent a curved four-dimensional spacetime as a surface in some higher-dimension flat spacetime, that's not what happens in general relativity.  General relativity and special relativity are both four-dimensional theories.

Comment: Yes, you can view a curved 4D spacetime manifold as a hypersurface isometrically embedded in a higher dimensional affine space. As noted by @dmckee above, this is not required to do the math in GR, but it is not prohibited either. Your error however is in thinking that this space would be just 5D (which is possible only in special cases). Generally the number of required dimensions would be much higher. For example, the Schwarzschild spacetime (e.g. the Earth gravity) can be isometrically embedded in 6 dimensions, but more complex solutions require a much higher number of embedding dimensions.

Comment: The relativity of acceleration implies it's equivalence to gravity (General Relativity). The relativity of jerk implies its equivalence to gravitational waves. I am not aware of any work on this equivalence, it would be prohibitively complex. Gravitational waves are a result of the linearized gravity (approximation). No exact solutions of the full gravitational equations exist for gravitational waves. Thus we don't know if jerk is relative or not. The same applies to snap, a time derivative of jerk. Therefore your question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity, acceleration, jerk, and any other time derivative of position can be defined in spaces of any dimension. They are all “relative” in that they can be different in different inertial frames.

You do *not* need four dimensions to represent relative acceleration, six dimensions to represent relative jerk, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Another question - similar to how gravity curves Minkowski Space in higher dimension, what leads to the 6th dimension? In other words, is there some sort of natural force that can be interpreted as a higher than 2nd derivative of position?

Comment: a force is always connected to the 2nd time derivative of the position, since force is mass times acceleration and acceleration is 2nd derivative. if it has higher or lower derivatives it is not a force by definition.

Comment: Nothing that I know of leads to the 6th dimension. Some versions of string theory predict that there are six *additional* dimensions, but that doesn't seem to be what you have in mind.

Comment: "*jerk, and any other* [higher] *time derivative* [...] *can be different in different inertial frames*" - Can you substantiate this? I am not aware of any theoretical proof or any experimental result. In other words, how would you rigorously disprove a claim that jerk is absolute? You would need to show the full equivalence of jerk to gravitational waves, but gravitational waves themselves already are not an exact solution, but only an approximation. Nathan Rosen (as in the Rosen-Einstein bridge) always believed that gravitational waves are canceled out by the non-linearity of the equations.

Comment: @MadhavRajesh No, this is not granted at all. (1) When you say, "time and space are relative", you need to be very clear what exactly this means. (2) Velocity is relative in Special Relativity and in Newtonian physics, but acceleration is absolute in both. So relativity of higher derivatives does not follow from relativity of lower components. (3) When you say, jerk is relative, you also need to be very clear. This means that there exists a frame, in which all physical laws are the same, but jerk is canceled out. By what? This is possible only in a gravitational wave. See my comments above.